# Can't add any Meta Sites released after M.SU to my Tag Set?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

It doesn't work if I do:

1. Add entire site
2. Enter "Meta Gam"
3. Let it auto-complete to "Meta Gaming"
4. Click on "add".

The loading animation shows up shortly, but it isn't added to the list.

---

It does work if I do:

1. Add entire site
2. Enter "Meta Sup"
3. Let it auto-complete to "Meta Super User"
4. Click on "add".

The loading anymation shows up shortly, and it is added to the list.

---

It seems to me that there is a problem adding Meta Sites past the SOFU sites to my Tag Set?

Comment: iirc, Gaming's not in Beta any more.

Comment: Right. I actually meant sites that were released after Super User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed.  It broke when we switched the name around from "Gaming Meta" to "Meta Gaming" (so the Meta part wouldn't get truncated on longer sites).  Now we match your submission against the correct name.

Comment: Confirmed, works for the meta sites I wanted to add. :-)